# Acquiring a special pointer value in a constexpr constructor (something like a "second" nullptr)

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a little `ListNode` struct:

```
struct ListNode {
    Object *prev;
    Object *next;

    constexpr ListNode() : prev(nullptr), next(nullptr) { }
};
```

A `ListNode` can be in two major states:

- part of a list
- not part of a list

When a `ListNode` is part of a list, its `prev` and `next` members can have two different kind of values:

- both are `nullptr` (it means, that the node is the only member of the list)
- one of them, or both are non-`nullptr`.

When a `ListNode` is not part of a list, its `prev` and `next` members don't contain useful information. When a `ListNode` is created, it gets into this state. `prev` and `next` members are initialized to `nullptr`.

Now, as you can see, the `ListNode` has the same state (`prev` and `next` are both `nullptr`), when:

- it is not in a list
- it is in a list, and it is the only member

Now, I'd like to differentiate between these two states, for **debug purposes** only. The idea is, when a `ListNode` is deleted, then before the delete, I check that the node is not in a list, because deleting a `ListNode` which is still in a list is a bug (and this can be used for more debug checks: before `ListNode` added to a List, it can be checked whether this `ListNode` is already in a list, etc).

So, I would need a special `Object` pointer, which is not `nullptr`, to specify the not-in-list state. So the constructor/destructor is like this:

```
constexpr ListNode() : prev(<special>), next(<special>) { }
~ListNode() { assert(prev==<special>&&next==<special>); }
```

Now, the question is, **how can I acquire a special `Object` pointer value for this purpose?**

A solution could be to use `reinterpret_cast`:

```
special = reinterpret_cast<Object*>(some_small_integer_value);
```

But I'm in a `constexpr` constructor, where `reinterpret_cast` is forbidden (and it is an ugly and fragile solution anyway).

Note, that in my actual code, `ListNode` is actually a template, and **`Object` can be anything, even a type with deleted/private default constructor, or an abstract class**.

Note2: of course, this problem could be easily solved by a simple `bool` member variable. However, it would increase the size of `ListNode` (and using this `bool` variable in debug builds only is not an option, as the debug and release builds of my library are binary compatible, and I'd like to retain this).

Comment: you would make a 'sentinal' node, that you set your pointers to point at when you remove a node from a list. Then you can compare with the address of the 'sentinal' node.

Comment: There is no around the fundamental fact that all the possible states cannot be represented unambiguously. Even using the sentinel node approach you have an abnormal state where one pointer points to the sentinel node, and the other one does not. To express the possible states accurately, and unambiguously, I would use a `std::optional` that contains the `prev` and `next` pointers. Specific and unambiguous: `std::optional` not set? Node is not part of the list. Node is a part of the list? Here are its `prev` and `next` pointers.

Comment: @dgsomerton: the question is, how to create such a sentinel node? A `ListNode` needs to have one, without ever being in a list, and needs to check it without a list.  The problem is, how to get a pointer to such a sentinel node?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: That means another kind of bug. Let's suppose that the functions which handles a `ListNode` are free of bugs, so these kind of abnormal states cannot happen.

Answer (score 3):

To make specific dgsomerton's comment

```
inline Object debug;
inline constexpr auto special = &debug;
```

And now `special` is a guaranteed unique and non-null pointer, suitable to be equality-tested against.

Comment: Are inline variables required to all have the same address?

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, otherwise they'd be quite useless. [Standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.inline#6.sentence-5).

Comment: The problem is more complex unfortunately. `ListNode`  contains `Object` pointers, not `ListNode` pointers. So, `special` needs to have the type of `Object *`, not `ListNode *`.

Comment: @geza just change it to `inline Object debug;`

Comment: @Caleth: "`Object` can be anything, even a type with deleted/private default constructor."

Comment: @geza - In that case, the OP can get a pointer to such an object only by dynamic memory allocation which means his list (and contents thereof) would be leaking memory. Pointless isint it?

Comment: @geza wait what? How is it a list node if it points to `Object`s?

Comment: @Caleth: `Object` can contain `ListNode` in several ways: it can be a member, or it can be derived from a `ListNode` (or even, I have a support, that `Object` provides its `ListNode` via a functor). It is an intrusive list implementation.

Comment: @Caleth: but I've found a way to solve this, if I put `Object` into a `union`. But I don't really like this solution, as I need to allocate space for an `Object`, just to have a pointer to it. It's not a big deal, as it is for debug only. But anyways, it would be much better, if I could just get a special pointer value somehow, without allocating space for it.

Comment: @geza A non-null pointer to a non-existent object that has specified equality comparison can only be an invalid pointer. But then the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion becomes implementation-defined. So just define an `Object` in debug mode.

Comment: You know, if you only want a unique pointer suitable for some type `T`, you can use `union { T t; } anchor;`, cutting out any (potentially non-existent or non-accessible) constructors.